# GCP - Remote access to server in a different ipsec connection

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine

We would like to access a remote server (customer infrastructure) from our Google Cloud Platform via our on-permises infra (where IPSec is already configured to access to costumer).

[Big picture of current solultion](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hrzhA.png)

We already configured a GCP route to the remote server using tunnel as next hop but with no success.

Any idea of the way to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

Basing in the topology you are sharing:

GCP -> On-prem DC -> Customer DC

You basically need to make sure GCP Cloud VPN configuration from GCP to On-prem DC is properly set up according to the following documentation:

a) [Cloud VPN Best Practices.](https://cloud.google.com/vpn/docs/resources/best-practices)

b) Assuming you are using Dynamic Routing as your type of Cloud VPN in GCP (which is the most recommendable one), double check [creation steps](https://cloud.google.com/vpn/docs/how-to/creating-vpn-dynamic-routes), like required permissions and so on.

c) The follow-up steps are very important as well, such as [configuring the correct firewall rules on GCP and on-premises. And setting up the on-premise VPN gateway and tunnel properly according to the device/brand you use on-prem.](https://cloud.google.com/vpn/docs/how-to/creating-vpn-dynamic-routes#follow-up_steps)

d) Since you mention you are using IPSec, please make sure which [IKE version you are using in GCP and on-prem](https://cloud.google.com/vpn/docs/how-to/configuring-on-premises-gateway), and to abide to the [GCP exact values for Phase 1 and 2.](https://cloud.google.com/vpn/docs/concepts/supported-ike-ciphers)

Answer (score 0):

Based on your question I can assume that you have:

- working VPN between your on-premise dc and GCP
- working VPN between your on-premise DC and customers DC

You said that you can't connect from GCP to the customer's network. That means traffic going from GCP to customer gets dropped at some point - either due to improper routing or much simpler thing like firewalls (check GCP Firewall in particular to make sure it doesn't block the traffic).

Double check those because one of them is the culprit here.